# serial read function synchronizing linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I have to share serial port *read* function with two other functions, basically

1. first function keeps polling on serial port read function for data every 1000 msec
2. when something is written to serial port , it has to read back ack/nack from serial port.

   Can anyone suggest how this synchronization can be achieved efficiently with mutex or any other synchronization functionality available in linux for common read function? I am not using any threads for these operation since this is done on polling basis.

Comment: If you are not using threads a mutex will not help you. If you are running a single threaded program you dont have to worry about synchronization as only one of your functions can be accessing the serial port at a given time

Comment: Thanks , but problem here is (1) above scenario keeps polling for serial port data every 1000 msec and (2) write to serial port can happen any time where it needs to access serial port read functionality to read ack/nack. what is happening now is when write functionality is done and waits for reading ack/nack other polling function (1) would receive ack/nack and not write function which wants return value from serial port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disable the polling while you wait for ack. You don't need a mutex because you're not using a thread, just use a global variable set by the writing function and read by the polling, so that you know if you have to skip polling.